# Siverlight: DataGridView adding items and getting selected items

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagridview

I use the `DataTable` for adding items to a `DataGridView` and the `DataGridRow` for getting the select items out of it in WPF but the silverlight appears not to have those types. I would like to know what the appropriate way is to add data and get them back to and from the `DataGridView` in silverlight since those things are not available in this framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to bind your data with the data grid view like that at all. (By using `DataTable`). Instead you you can make a list of your models and directly bind it to the item source of the grid view. For example:

```
// Example Model
public class MyModel{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public String Title {get; set;
}

List<MyModel> MyList = new List<MyModel>(){ new MyModel{ Id = 1, Title = "Jack"}};
MyDataGridView.ItemSource = MyList;
```

And to get the selected row you can:

```
var Row = (MyModel) MyDataGridView.SelectedItem;
```